# 8x8 Knights Tour Java Out of Memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, backtracking, knights-tour

This code works perfectly for 5x5,6x6,7x7 but runs out of memory in 8x8. I increased memory up to 2048M and it still doesn't work. Code is supposed to use Stack class and backtracking as parts of the solution
Here is the code:

```
private int counter=0;
private boolean grid[][]=new boolean [ROWS][COLS];
private  Stack tour=new Stack(0,0);
private int spaces=ROWS*COLS;
private int[][] intGrid=new int[ROWS][COLS];


private static final Point[] Moves=new Point[]{
    new Point(-1, -2),
    new Point(-1, 2),
    new Point(1, -2),
    new Point(1, 2),
    new Point(-2, -1),
    new Point(-2, 1),
    new Point(2, -1),
    new Point(2, 1),
};

public void run(){
    fillIntGrid();
    tourFrom(tour.first);
    println("SOLUTION FOUND:");
    printBoard();
}

public boolean tourFrom(Point currPoint){
    counter++;
    grid[currPoint.xCoord][currPoint.yCoord] = true;
    intGrid[currPoint.xCoord][currPoint.yCoord]=counter;
    if(counter==spaces)
        return true;
    for(Point nextMove:Moves){
        int nextRow=currPoint.xCoord+nextMove.xCoord;
        int nextCol =currPoint.yCoord+nextMove.yCoord;
        tour.push(nextRow,nextCol);
        if(nextRow<0 || nextRow>=grid.length)
            continue;
        else if(nextCol<0 || nextCol>=grid.length)
            continue;
        else if(grid[nextRow][nextCol])
            continue;
        if(tourFrom(tour.first))
            return true;
        } 
    grid[currPoint.xCoord][currPoint.yCoord] = false;
    intGrid[currPoint.xCoord][currPoint.yCoord]=0;
    counter--;
    tour.pop();
    return false;
}

public void fillIntGrid(){
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            intGrid[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

What can be the possible problem?

Comment: Looks like you have a memory leak in some part of your code. From the current given code, I cannot identify it. Probably you should post more of your code e.g. how you invoke these methods from your main method.

Comment: This is full code. I can post the text of the Error if it will help.

Comment: I do not know any Java program that can be executed without a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Post all the relevant code to inspect where your problem may lie, or do it the hard (but always better) way: generate a heap dump, use a memory analyzer like [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and spot the memory leaks in your app.

Comment: It's `if(tourFrom(tour.first))`. It's just calling itself infinitely. No matter how much memory you give it, it will still overflow. I think you meant to write something like `if(tourFrom(put_the_current_point_here))`

Comment: First check for infinite loops, then use an memory analysis tool. NetBeans comes with one, or you can use the link Luiggi posted for Eclipse.

Comment: Added an answer because it seems no one caught on to the info in my comment

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a programming exercise ...

Hint: compare the number of `push` calls and `pop` calls made in the body of `tourFrom`.

---

OK, so here is the logic I used to figure that out.

It is not an infinite recursion problem, because that would have given a `StackOverflowError`, not an `OutOfMemoryError`.

An `OutOfMemoryError` means a storage leak of some kind.  (There could potentially be other problems ... but lets pursue the storage leak idea.)

Q: Which is the only data structure that is potentially unbounded in size?

A: The Stack.

Q: How can that grow infinitely?

A: If you do more pushes than pops.

So look at the push and pop code ...

---

Q:  But how come 6x6 and 7x7 (supposedly) work?

A:  Do the math :-)

---

Stepping back and looking at the solution, there are other issues.  For example, you are not making use of the value returned by `tourFrom`.  And that means that you will always report that a solution is found, and you won't stop when a solution is found.

I'm really doubtful that >>this<< code worked properly for smaller board sizes.